# How make decision tree's labels visibles in R?

Tags: r

I'm working in Machine learning problem and I'm using a  Decision trees to make  conclusions using the code shown bellow:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(rpart.plot)
library(rpart)
library(rattle)

set.seed(27)
fit <- rpart(Achat_client ~ .,
             data = train_,
             method = "class",
             control = rpart.control(xval = 10, minbucket = 2, cp = 0), parms = list(split = "information"))

fancyRpartPlot(fit)
```

But I get a warnings message :

> Warning message: labs do not fit even at cex 0.15, there may be some
>   overplotting

And my decision tree is having labels which are invisible at all.
 [image: You can see it here]

how can i deal with this problem please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try exporting to PDF and zoom in through a PDF viewer:

```
pdf("tree.pdf")
fancyRpartPlot(fit)
dev.close()
system("evince tree.pdf") # If you have the evince PDF viewer installed
```

Comment: Thank you !! I can also play with the parameter minbucket !

Comment: Sure - the tree is probably too large, so there are various parameters to rpart() that you can play around with to produce a more compact tree, including minbucket.

Comment: Notice in order to use fancyRpartPlot you have to import rattle.

install.packages("rattle")
library(rattle)